# cannot return non-composite value from function returning composite type

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a 2 tables named ticket and ticket update

- ticket (ticketID, problem, status (set to either open or closed), priority, logged_time, customerID, productID)
- ticketupdate (ticketupdateID, updatemessage, updatetime, ticketID, staffID)

I want to make a trigger so when I insert values into the ticketupdate table it checks the status of the ticket table to see if it open or closed. If it is closed then it would prevent me from inserting the values.

I created a trigger and function as follows:

```sql
create or replace function check_status()
returns trigger as $BODY$
BEGIN
  return (select status from ticket where new.ticketID = ticket.ticketID);
  if ticket.status = 'open' then
    insert into ticketupdate values (ticketupdateid, update_message,    
current_timestamp, ticketID, staffID);
  else
    raise exception 'Status of the ticket is closed, no further action necessary.';
  end if;
end;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger update_ticket
after update on ticket
for each row
execute procedure check_status();
```

However when I insert the values in I get an error message saying: Cannot return non-composite value from function returning composite type

Answer (score 2):

A trigger function needs to return the `new` or `old` record. You seem to confuse the `return` statement with an assignment.

Because the trigger is defined on the `ticket` table, there is no need to run a select to access the value of the `status` column. You can access it directly through the `new` record.

It's also good coding practice to list all target columns in an INSERT statement.

It's unclear to me, where the values for your INSERT should come from, I have marked the missing parts with `??`. Assuming `ticketupdateid` is an identity (or serial) column, you probably shouldn't provide a value for it. But you still need a value for `update_message` and `staffid` to come from somewhere.

So you probably are looking for something along the lines:

```
create or replace function check_status()
  returns trigger 
as 
$BODY$
begin
  if new.status = 'open' then
    insert into ticketupdate (updatemessage, updatetime, ticketid, staffid)
    values (??, current_timestamp, new.ticketid, ??);
  else
    raise exception 'Status of the ticket is closed, no further action necessary.';
  end if;
  
  return new;  -<< required for a trigger
end;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

What @a_horse_with_no_name indicates in by far the most common usage to disallow a DML statement. The problem, in some situations, being that that it aborts the entire transaction. However Postgres offers an alternative. You can return NULL to cancel that particular row, but others to continue.  From the documentation:

> A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value
> having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.
>
> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger
> manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
> subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
> not occur for this row).

So perhaps:

```
create or replace function check_status()
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin
   if old.status = 'closed' then
      raise log 'Ticket % is closed, no further action allowed.',old.ticketid;
      return null; 
   end if; 
   
   insert into ticketupdate (updatemessage, updatetime, ticketid, staffid)
        values (??, current_timestamp, new.ticketid, ??);

  return new;  
end;
$$; 
  
create trigger update_ticket
before update on ticket           --- must be BEFORE
for each row
execute procedure check_status();
```

**NOTICE Raise log:** It is critical you generate a message here somehow indicating the update was not performed. You could just write to the ticketupdate table with a 'rejected' message. Not providing an easily accessible message just generates confusion that appears as a hard to find bug, when it is actually the desired course of action.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to return the record type value `'("John",27)'` from `my_func()` as shown below. *I referred to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-CONSTRUCTING) about **Constructing Composite Values**:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN '("John",27)';
END;  -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` got the same error below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  cannot return non-composite value from function returning composite type
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at RETURN
```

So, I used [ROW()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) to create the record type value `ROW('John',27)` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN ROW('John',27);
END;  -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
  my_func
-----------
 (John,27)
(1 row)
```